# Item cannot be found in the collection correspoding to the requested name or ordinal

Tags: ms-access, vb6

Trying to auto generate a sales id. But I don't know why I am getting this error.

```
Set qs = New ADODB.Recordset
qs.Open "select * from DailyRecords ", db, 3, 2
With qs
   If .RecordCount = 0 Then
      txtsalesID.Text = "S-0001"
   Else
      qs.MoveLast
      txtsalesID.Text = "S-" & Format(Right(qs!SalesID, 4) + 1, "0000") // this line is producing the error
   End If
```

I have even checked the database field name. It's the same as SalesID. I tried a lot and seeking for help

Comment: Are you using VBA or VB6? They are not the same thing.

Comment: i'm using VB6, not VBA. The tag added accidentally, I shall remove it

Comment: I mentioned specifically, I have double checked database fields. It's correct.

Comment: Have you checked your Recordset for the field name?

Comment: If that's the line this error message is occurring on, then the name is probably not correct.  Check the recordset fields collection for the number of columns (`qs.Fields.Count`) and the names of the columns returned (`qs.Fields(0).Name`, then 1, 2, etc).  You could also try to reference the column through the Fields property collection, rather than the `!` shortcut: `qs.Fields("SalesID").Value`

Comment: Tried Everything, that particular reference SalesID is giving me error on every form, even though the filed name in db is SalesID

Comment: Try setting a break point on the line, `With qs`. Then paste and run this line on code in the immediate window. Make sure the entire line is on a single line. It will print out the field names in your recordset.
`For i = 0 To qs.Fields.Count - 1 : Debug.Print qs.Fields(i).Name : Next i`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you use `RecordCount` to check if the recordset is empty. The `RecordCount` leaves the cursor at the end of the recordset so you you will not be able to read data from the record, even if there are records. You should use `EOF` instead:

```
   If .EOF Then
      txtsalesID.Text = "S-0001"
   Else
      qs.MoveLast
      txtsalesID.Text = "S-" & Format(Right(qs!SalesID, 4) + 1, "0000")
   End If
```